# What is the relation between polynomial factorisation and field size?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Please kindly let me know if the question is not suitable for this forum or duplicated.

---

Assume all operations and polynomials are defined and done on $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a large prime number of size $z$ bits.

**Question**: What is the complexity of factorizing a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q$? How does the size of $q$ play a role in the factorization complexity?

Comment: [Wikipedia has a lot to say about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Complexity). The size of $q$ comes to play in two ways. 1) via the complexity of individual arithmetic operations in $\Bbb{F}_q$, and 2) in [Cantor-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) via the first step in the Euclidean algorithm when computing the remainder of a $O(q^d)$th power of a polynomial (requiring $O(\log q)$ iterations). So the overall effect of $q$ is a factor that is polynomial in $\log q$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the answer! just to clarify $log$ here is base 2, is that right?

Comment: Yes. Though the difference in logarithms w.r.t. different bases can be absorbed into the constant in the big-Oh.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen a quick question: am I right that the complexity is $log 2^z$ as it should be $log$ of the number of field elements? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. If your field has $q=2^m$ elements then $\log q=m$.