# Relation between Polynomial factorisation and field size in theory and practice.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

My question is related to this:

[What is the relation between polynomial factorisation and field size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881207/what-is-the-relation-between-polynomial-factorisation-and-field-size?noredirect=1#comment5948503_2881207)

---

Assume all operations and polynomials are defined and done on $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a large prime number of size $z$ bits.
As stated in the above post and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717199910027), the complexity of factorizing a polynomial of degree $n$ is $O(n^c log 2^z)$ , where $1< c \leq 2$.

Consider the case where we have two polynomials of the same degree one is defined on a field of size $112$-bit and the other one on a $40$-bit field. Then, to calculate the runtime difference between the two polynomials we can have:

$$\frac{\log(2^{112})}{\log(2^{40})}= 2.8.$$

But, when I run [NTL](https://www.shoup.net/ntl/) library (so I have written the code in C++) to factorize two polynomials specified above the ratio would be about: $2.19$. That means the implementation is faster than the asymptotic analysis.

**Question**: Is my analysis above correct? If yes, why the running time in practice is faster than the asymptotic analysis?